# Urls with special characters are not converted correctly by SendGrid

Tags: special-characters, url-encoding, sendgrid

I have a url in one of my emails for twitter share that looks like:
`http://twitter.com/share?text=Praneeta%27s%20test&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%3Fparam1%3D303%26param2%3Dtest&related=praneeta&via=Praneeta`

However SendGrid converts only the part before the `'`  (encoded as %27)

So the url I have in the emails sent is broken and looks like
`http://email.mydomain.com/wf/click?upn=<long_encoded_key>%27s%27s%20test&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%3Fparam1%3D303%26param2%3Dtest&related=praneeta&via=Praneeta`

Is there a work around for this?

note: If I copy the email html and send it to myself via putsmail, it works fine, it breaks only when it goes via Sendgrid.

Answer (score 3):

I just sent the link you posted through my own SendGrid account and it looks like it was properly encoded. I wonder if this was a temporary issue? What happens if you try sending that link again?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. After a lot of digging I realized this was my fault. The url was NOT correctly encoded. I was previewing the email in a Chrome browser and when I did 'copy link address', it gave me the encoded url. I was using `URI.encode` by Rails which does not encode the `'`. I switched to using `CGI.encode`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up on this issue incase if people stumble on this.  The method should be `escape` for example:

`CGI::escape('\'')`